# Publishing for Release and specific OS in the same time doesn't work for .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core

I'm trying the following command for my .NET Core 3.1. Console application in the folder D:\core:

> D:\core>dotnet publish -c Release –r ubuntu-x64 --self-contained true

And it gives an error:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified. Switch:
> ubuntu-x64
>
> For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"

When I use these two commands separately they work perfectly fine, but I need Release for Ubuntu; when I don't try to specify Release for Ubuntu it creates Publish folder in Debug folder:

> D:\core>dotnet publish –r ubuntu-x64 --self-contained true

> D:\core>dotnet publish -c Release

To summarize, the problem is that I can't currently publish for Release for a specified OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `–r` in your command. That's a em-dash (`–`) followed by an `r`. Have you tried using a normal dash/hyphen?

That works for me:

```
$ dotnet new console
Getting ready...
The template "Console Application" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on /home/omajid/temp/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.csproj...
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /home/omajid/temp/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.csproj (in 66 ms).

Restore succeeded.

$ dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu-x64 --self-contained true
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.0-preview-20220-01+80e487bff for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /home/omajid/temp/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.csproj (in 16.86 sec).
  You are using a preview version of .NET. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  HelloWorld -> /home/omajid/temp/HelloWorld/bin/Release/net5.0/ubuntu-x64/HelloWorld.dll
  HelloWorld -> /home/omajid/temp/HelloWorld/bin/Release/net5.0/ubuntu-x64/publish/
```

---

Aside: you should use the `linux-x64` runtime id rather than `ubuntu-x64`. `linux-x64` is compatible with Ubuntu, but also many other distributions too.

Comment: Thank you. The command "dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu-x64 --self-contained true" worked for me.